# ios UIPickerView scrolling too fast

Tags: ios, objective-c, scroll, uitextfield, uipickerview

I am using a `UIPickerView` in conjunction with a `UITextField` to input values into the textField. The pickerView displays a range of numbers where each number is equivalent to the row in the picker view.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent: NSInteger)component
{
    return self.max + 1;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row];
}
```

When a user selects a value in the picker the text field should reflect that value:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:      (NSInteger)component
{
    self.quantityField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row];
}
```

However, I am noticing that if I spin the picker too quickly, the row passed to `didSelectRow` occasionally will not match the row that is settled upon in the picker. Any thoughts on why this is happening and how to prevent this?

[image]

The field with the 6 in it represents my `UITextField`. As you can see the picker is settled on the 10.

My complete set up is as follows:

I have a `UITableView` with a number of custom `UITableViewCells`. 
Each cell has a `UITextField` which is referred to with `self.quantityField`.

I set the following up:

```
// pickerView represents the UIPickerView.
self.quantityField.inputView = self.pickerView;
UIToolbar *myToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,_pickerView.frame.origin.y - 44, self.frame.size.width, 44)];

UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(inputAccessoryViewDidFinish)];
doneButton.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[myToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject: doneButton] animated:NO];

self.quantityField.inputAccessoryView = myToolbar;
```

To make sure that I close the picker view when the done button is clicked I implemented the following function (which was added as the `action` for the `doneButton`.

```
- (void)inputAccessoryViewDidFinish
{
    [self.quantityField resignFirstResponder];   
}
```

Each picker is set to show the numbers 0-10 (11 rows).

Comment: `didSelectRow` is triggered only when you **stop** on a row. Are you sure you still have an error with this information ?

Comment: yes, I'm positive. adding screenshot to the main post

Comment: I have copied your code and worked on it, well at my end it is working perfectly fine! you might be doing something else somewhere! If you have anything else share that aswell please

Comment: hmm ok, it only happens when i drag the picker all the way immediately. other than that it works fine. probably not too big a deal.

Comment: how many rows do you have and can you explain the exact scenario you are following? if you are facing something like this i also should be able to reproduce!

Comment: Sure, I have 11 rows (numbered 0-10 on the picker).

Comment: I edited my main post to show exactly what my setup is

Answer (score 1):

[i have added a repo of the same](https://github.com/harsh62/stackoverflowTest.git) which is working perfectly fine, monkey tested it!

If still the problem persists, make changes in the repo as per your current app which has the issue and will then look into it further!